# How to get the new value of the element ? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry I'm a beginner in JavaScript and this question has been certainly allready asked but I don't find any answer.
I think it was very simple but I do this :

```
<h1 onclick="up()" id="titre">Le texte du titre</h1>
<div id="div">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<img src="Koala.jpg">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function descend() {
        var cour = document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop;
        var cour = (cour+50);
        document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop = cour;
    }

    function up() {
        setInterval(descend, 2000);
    }
</script>
```

So in this script when I click on the H1 I launch the function `up()` which launch the function `descend()` with 2sec interval. The problem is when I get the marginTop value at the second turn it does'nt increment.
(I know I have also another little problem. I need to express the new value in px)
How can I do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`marginTop` will return the value with the `px` suffix. So you won't be able to do `(cour + 50)`. `parseInt` will help you out.

```js
var cour = parseInt(document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop, 10)
```

`marginTop` will return `'50px'`, and `parseInt` will convert that to `50`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

https://codepen.io/ayhandoslu/pen/vYYPzYR?editors=1001

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function descend() {
        var cour = +(document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop || "0px").replace("px", "");
        var cour = (cour+50);
        document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop = cour + "px";
    }

    function up() {
        setInterval(descend, 2000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the empty top margin and after setting margin with div

```
<h1 onclick="up()" id="titre">Le texte du titre</h1>
<div id="div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<img src="Koala.jpg">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function descend() {

    var cour = document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop;
    if(cour === ""){
    document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop = "50px";
    return
    }
    var newvalues = parseInt(cour.substring(0,cour.indexOf("px")));

    var cour = (newvalues + 50);
    document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop = cour+"px";
  }

  function up() {
    setInterval(descend, 2000);
  }
</script>
```

you need to set margin as any unit as per your requirement and during calculation need to remove that unit like above code

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1 onclick="up()" id="titre">Le texte du titre</h1>
<div id="div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<img src="Koala.jpg">
<script type="text/javascript">
   function descend() {
        var cour = document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop;
        if (cour === "") {
            cour = 0;
        }
        cour = (cour + 50);
        var newcour= cour + "px";
        document.getElementById("div").style.marginTop = newcour;
    }

    function up() {
        setInterval(descend, 2000);
    }
</script>
```